# Scala: filter multiple elements of a list

Tags: scala, filter, functional-programming

Assuming I have these scala classes:

```
Task(id: String, pr: List[PhysicalResource])

PhysicalResource(id: String)
```

A `list: List[PhysicalResource]` with these elements:

```
("PR1" :: "PR2" :: "PR3" :: "PR4" :: Nil)
```

And this `obj: Task` object:

```
("T1", List(PhysicalResource("PR1"), PhysicalResource("PR3")))
```

I want to return the first two elements  (two, because `obj.physicalResources.size = 2`) of list that match the Physical Resources of the object.

In this example I want to return:

```
("PR1" :: "PR3" :: Nil)
```

I am doing this, but it doesn't return anything:

```
list.filter{x => obj.physicalResources.contains(x)}
```

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: What does `obj.physicalResources.contains(x)` return? `filter` should work for this, but I'm having a hard time testing this as I haven't used Scala in awhile. Can you post an [MCVE]? I can't find what a `PhyscialResource` is.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your issue using `filter`:

```
val resources: List[String] =
 ("PR1" :: "PR2" :: "PR3" :: "PR4" :: Nil)

// Representing obj.physicalResources
val physicalResources: List[String] =
 ("PR1" :: "Something Else" :: "PR3" :: Nil)

val filtered: List[String] =
  resources.filter{x => physicalResources.contains(x)}

println(filtered)

// Prints List(PR1, PR3)
```

But try this way that uses `intersect`:

```
// Take the intersection of the 2 lists; the parts that are the same
println(resources.intersect(physicalResources))

// Prints List(PR1, PR3)
```

Rolling your own method to accomplish this seems a little excessive.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came up with a generic solution for a similar problem:

```
def hasSubsequence[A](sup: List[A], sub: List[A]): Boolean = {
  def hasSubsequenceR[A](sup1: List[A], sub1: List[A]): Boolean = sup1 match {
    case x :: xs => sub1 match {
      case y :: ys if x == y => hasSubsequenceR(xs, ys)
      case Nil => true
      case _ => hasSubsequenceR(xs, sub)
   }
   case _ => false
 }
 hasSubsequenceR(sup, sub)
}
```

where sup is your `list` and sub is your `obj.pr`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to match `obj`'s PhysicalResource `id`s against the master `list`.  List of PhysicalResource `id`s in `obj` is `obj.pr.map(_.id)`, hence you can use `intersect` between the two lists to get the matching `id`s as follows:

```
case class PhysicalResource(id: String)
case class Task(id: String, pr: List[PhysicalResource])

val list: List[String] = "PR1" :: "PR2" :: "PR3" :: "PR4" :: Nil

val obj: Task = Task("T1", List(PhysicalResource("PR1"), PhysicalResource("PR3")))

list.intersect(obj.pr.map(_.id))
res1: List[String] = List(PR1, PR3)
```